# Setting up web payment using paypal

Tags: angularjs, paypal

I'm working on a project and they have are planning to add a feature web payment. I'm glad to say that our client is a technical person and told me to use the paypal. This is my first time integrating a web payment. I've read some docs in developers.paypal and i'm planning to use the paypal express checkout.

Furthermore I'll be developing this using only client side (Angularjs), is it right decision for me to use paypal express checkout? Will I encounter some security issue here since its client side? The main idea is upon successful payment I have to sync an http request that will trigger that the user has paid.

Sample idea

```
.success(function(){
   $http.post(...)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it's a complete example that will help you:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576246/A-Shopping-Cart-Application-Built-with-AngularJS